# Have IH₃ and IH₅ already been synthesized?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, synthesis, hydrogen

I've seen a paper by Sikalov [[1](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00214-019-2524-0)] that says that $\ce{IH3}$ and $\ce{IH5}$ should be observable. Has anyone actually tried to synthesize such molecules?

#### References

1. Sikalov, A. A. Hypervalent Halogen Hydrides $\ce{HalH_n}$ ($\ce{Hal}$ = $\ce{Cl},$ $\ce{Br},$ $\ce{I};$ $n = 3, 5, 7)$: DFT and Ab Initio Stability Prediction. *Theor Chem Acc* **2019**, 139 (1), 8. DOI: [10.1007/s00214-019-2524-0](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00214-019-2524-0).

Comment: I've done some literature research but couldn't find anything...

Comment: Under high pressure, maybe? Also is there a reason to put iodine first not hydrogen as in ordinary hydrogen iodide?

Comment: Oscar Lanzi , in this case, some of Hydrogen atoms are negatively charged. That's probably why the author uses such notation.

Answer (score 2):

Not the specific compounds $\ce{IH3}$ and $\ce{IH5}$, but hydrogen-iodine compounds with nonclassical stoichiometriws have been synthesized under high pressure.

Binns et al[[1](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.97.024111)] report two high-pressure, hydrogen-rich hydrogen iodides. The more widely stable one, with empirical formula $\ce{H_{27}I}$ consisting of a hydrogen iodide molecule isolated in a shell of thirteen dihydrogen molecules, is stable from 9 to at least 130 GPa pressure. The second compound, stable up to 12.5 GPa, has two hydrogen iodide molecules per one dihydrogen molecules for an empirical formula $\ce{H2I}$. Both compounds are characterized by synchrotron XRD and Raman spectroscopy, and both have only secondary bonding between the hydrogen iodide component and additional hydrogen rather than hypercoordinated iodine.

**Reference**

1. Jack Binns, Philip Dalladay-Simpson, Mengnan Wang, Graeme J. Ackland, Eugene Gregoryanz, and Ross T. Howie (2018)."Formation of H2-rich iodine-hydrogen compounds at high pressure".
   *Phys. Rev. B* **97**, 024111. https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.97.024111